# Some notes, literature on grassmanians

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can anybody provide a link to some notes on grassmanians? I mean something 'elementary': description of Plucker embedding, lines and hyperplanes on grassmanians and so on.

Comment: "Elementary" often means "with coordinates", which makes basics such as the Plücker embedding incredibly complicated (as compared to the coordinate-free version).

Answer (score 2):

Paolo Piccione and Daniel Victor Tausk's ["A Student’s Guide to Symplectic Spaces, Grassmannians and Maslov Index"](http://www.ime.usp.br/~piccione/Downloads/MaslovBook.pdf) is a good textbook to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Joe Harris's "[Algebraic Geometry: A First Course](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387977163)" has a dedicated chapter about the Grassmannian. Also, there are computations of the degree, tangent space, etc. (the style is a bit hard to follow, though)